# Get json array values using PLSQL

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I am trying to import an array of numbers from a json response. The response of that json would look like this:

```
 [
   {
      "name": "Secondary",
      "levels": [7,8,9,10,11]
   } 
 ]
```

I've already obtain the name object and i can count the levels array with the following code.

```sql
DECLARE
v_response CLOB;
BEGIN
     apex_web_service.G_request_headers(1).name := 'Content-Type';
     apex_web_service.G_request_headers(1).value := 'application/json';

     v_response := apex_web_service.Make_rest_request(
                p_url => '<API>',
                p_http_method => 'GET'
             );

    apex_json.Parse(l_clob);

    for i in 1..apex_json.get_count(p_path => '.') loop
       dbms_output.put_line('name: ' || apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => '[%d].name', p0 => i));
         for j in 1..apex_json.get_count(p_path => '[%d].levels', p0 => i) loop
               dbms_output.put_line(apex_json.get_count(p_path => '[%d].levels', p0 => i));
         end loop;
     end loop;
END;
```

The expected result I need is to cycle through the levels array and insert the numbers to a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE
  l_json_text VARCHAR2(32767);
  l_json_values    apex_json.t_values;
BEGIN
  /*
    define json object inline - a lot easier to debug
  */
  l_json_text := '[
     {
        "name": "First",
        "levels": [2,3,4,5,6]
     }, 
     {
        "name": "Secondary",
        "levels": [7,8,9,10,11]
     }
   ]
  ';

  /*
  parse json
  */
  apex_json.parse(
    p_values => l_json_values,
    p_source => l_json_text
  );
  /*
    this json object is defined as an array - which seems a bit unusual. Most of the sample code has a root object which makes parsing this particular
    json a bit odd.  Loop through the elements of the array in the root path 
  */
  FOR i IN 1..apex_json.get_count(p_path => '.', p_values => l_json_values) LOOP
    /*
      get value for name attribute for each name attribute
    */
    dbms_output.put_line('name: ' || apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => '['||i||'].name', p0 => I, p_values => l_json_values));
    /*
      loop through the elements of each levels attribute. 
    */
    FOR j IN 1..apex_json.get_count(p_path => '['||i||'].levels', p0 => I, p_values => l_json_values) LOOP
       dbms_output.put_line(apex_json.get_number(p_path => '['||i||'].levels[%d]', p0 => j, p_values => l_json_values));
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: I am recommending to use comments on the code to describe what you did. 

+1, Thanks.

Comment: Edited. The json object itself is defined as an array which made the parsing a bit different from the sample code you find everywhere.